# listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:80 - macOS

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, permissions

I need to serve an angular app with specific --host flag and --port 80. I added the host to my /etc/hosts file but when i use command "ng serve --host local.xxx.xxx --port 80", it says [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsFpC.png) :

```
To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
An unhandled exception occurred: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:80
See "/private/var/folders/vs/dflrxx851ds_nd29vrsw6t6r0000gn/T/ng-kMuSPm./angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Log contains of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkuLL.png) :

```
[error] Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net@1363:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1428:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1567:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:85:8)
```

Please note that it needs to be port 80. I can't serve it on another port because of CORS policy.

Comment: use sudo before the command.

Comment: this doesn't seem to resolve the issue for me

Comment: have you resolved this issue? thanks!

Comment: yes, sudo before the command solved the issue for me, thanks :)